# where is the 'size' for a pointer is allocated in the heap

Tags: size, heap-memory, allocation

This error happens at the end of the program when I try to free() a pointer

```js
Error in `./out': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x3ad1aa70
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xf7556377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xf755c2f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6e48a)[0xf755d48a]
./vx_tutorial_exe(main+0x12b2)[0x808533f]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7)[0xf7507637]
```

I think some other pointer is going out of bounds somewhere and deleting the size of my pointer in the heap.
If I can find the address of the heap record for the pointer, i guess I can put a hw watchpoint and find who's doing it

Any ideas ?

Comment: We can't really help you with just the error message. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you're using gcc, then you can add bounds checking. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Pointer-Bounds-Checker-builtins.html. That should tell you where things are going awry.